How to use the LaTxT editor on this site to type the δ symbol in the roman type
I want to type Kronecker delta notation, such as $\delta_{ij}$ , but I prefer a roman type font (rather than an italic one) in my answer, like this:
$\\mathrm{\delta}_{ij}$" />
The above picture was obtained using the $\mathrm{\delta}$ command in the AxMath software. However, command \mathrm{\delta} or \text{δ} or does not work here (Stack Exchange).

I don't know if this is due to a difference in $\mathrm\LaTeX$ versions or something else, but I want to output the standard δ symbol using the formula editor on this site. Can anyone help me?

(PS: I have seen books that use the Kronecker delta symbol in the regular roman format, and I prefer this one myself.)

MathJax does not implement all of $\LaTeX$. You'll just have to live with the limitations here.

There are a few ways, but they do not use the \delta command:



Description
MathJax
Result




Mathematical small bold delta
\unicode{120517}
$\unicode{120517}$


Latin small letter delta
\unicode{7839}
$\unicode{7839}$


Roman style delta using fonts where unicode 948 is δ on the Greek keyboard
\mathsfδ , \mathbb{\unicode{948}},etc
$\mathsf{\unicode{948}}$



You can define a new command like \def\rmdelta{\mathsfδ} or \newcommand\rmdelta{\mathsfδ} to implement the MathJax command into your post.

All of these will make it harder for others to either edit or reuse the LaTeX in your posts, and I think it would be better if you didn't use them.

@JonathanZ These are just interesting work-arounds to the LaTeX limitation and do not have to be used.

Yes, I appreciate you providing the information, but I wanted to at least mention that there might be some downsides to using them, as no-one had said anything about that yet.
